# How to express and solve this minimization problem in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

Let $T>0$, $H>0$, $D$, and $No>0$ are known parameter.

Let $\{p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_T\}$ are the optimization variables.

Let $\{w_1,w_2,\cdots, w_T\}$ are known parameters.

Now, I want to perform the following optimization

minimize $\sum_{t=1}^Tp_t$

subject to $\sum_{t=1}^Tw_t\log_2\left(1+\frac{Hp_t}{w_t No}\right)=Do$

I want to express $P_t$ as a function of other parameters.

I want to do it as follows

```
W = Array[w, T];
P = Array[p, T];

Expr = Total[W Log2[1 + H P/(W No)]];

Assuming[H > 0 && No > 0 && T > 0 && Do > 0, Simplify[Minimize[{Total[P], Expr == Do}, P]]]
```

How to denote $W$ and $P$ so that I can perform the optimization and express $P_t$ as a function of other system parameters?

Comment: `N` and `D` are already defined in Mathematica, you shouldn't use them for variables.  More constructively, if you put in your known values for H, N, T, D, and the w_i, the minimisation you've written should work.

Comment: @AnotherShruggingPhysicist, Thank you very much. But I need to express $p_t$ in a symbolic form.

Comment: Since this is a frequent issue: Do you just _want_ $p_t$ in symbolic form or do you _really_ need it in symbolic form?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I really need it in symbolic form. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in a symbolic solution, I would propose to investigate the KKT-conditions for this optimization problem. Here a quick script that generates them for $T=5$ variables. (`\[Lambda]` is a Lagrange multiplier.)

```
Off[Part::partd]
T = 5;
W = Table[w[[i]], {i, 1, T}];
P = Table[p[[i]], {i, 1, T}];
F = P \[Function] Evaluate[Total[P]];
DF = P \[Function] Evaluate[D[F[P], {P, 1}]];
G = p \[Function] Evaluate[Total[W + Log[1 + c P/W]]];
DG = p \[Function] Evaluate[D[G[P], {P, 1}]];
eq = Join[DF[P] + \[Lambda] DG[P], {G[P] - c0}];
Thread[eq == 0]
```

[image]

These can be simplified a bit; moreover, I eleminated `\[Lambda]`:

```
eq2 = Join[Table[w[[i]] + c p[[i]] + c \[Lambda], {i, 1, T}], eq[[{-1}]]];
lambdasol = Solve[Total[eq2[[1 ;; T]]] == 0, \[Lambda]][[1]];
p1sol = Solve[eq2[[-1]] == 0, p[[1]]][[1]] /. ConditionalExpression[bla_, blubb_] :> bla;
eq3 = T eq2[[1 ;; T-1]] /. lambdasol /. p1sol // Expand;
Thread[eq3 == 0]
```

[image]

Multiplying everything by with the nasty denominator would produce `T-1` polynomial equations of order `T` in the `T-1`variables `p[[2]]`,...,`p[[T]]`. Good luck with solving them!